# how to build Navigator() if use Getx?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

if we use `MaterialApp`, we build like this:

```
Navigator(
                key: naviKey,
                onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) => MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context)=>Container(),
                ),
              )
```

and now, how to build if we use `Getx`?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?? I've run into the same problem while trying to implement this - https://codewithandrea.com/articles/multiple-navigators-bottom-navigation-bar/

Answer (score 1):

Routing in GetX can be setup like so. Note `Page1.id` is after putting `static const id = 'page_1` in `Page1` so you don't have to use raw strings.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
      routes: {
        Page1.id: (context) => Page1(),
        Page2.id: (context) => Page2(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

or like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
      getPages: [
       GetPage(name: Page1.id, page: () =>  Page1()),
       GetPage(name: Page1.id, page: () =>  Page1()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can setup the list of routes on another page if you don't want to clutter up your `GetMaterialApp` with all your routes.

Then when you want to navigate you can do it like this

```
Get.to(Page2());
```

Comment: i want to implement inner navigation without changing parent

Comment: i want to use the transition like this "/ home / next_page / next / next / next"

Comment: Using named routes doesn't work for certain use cases. For example I'm trying to implement this - https://codewithandrea.com/articles/multiple-navigators-bottom-navigation-bar/ , which is not possible without Navigator's onGenerateRoute

Answer (score 0):

From GetX documentation in github, I found this:

```
Navigator(
  key: Get.nestedKey(1), // create a key by index
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/') {
      return GetPageRoute(
        page: () => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Main"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
                Get.toNamed('/second', id:1); // navigate by your nested route by index
              },
              child: Text("Go to second"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (settings.name == '/second') {
      return GetPageRoute(
        page: () => Center(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Main"),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child:  Text("second")
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
),
```

I think it is useful for your question